# I want to input a number or word and find out how many whole number were entered

Tags: python

**I have tried this code and it hasn't worked if I enter a number I am getting an error with code. Does anyone have a solution to why it not working?**

```py
def main():
    string=int(input("How many strings do you want to enter? "))

    for num in range(1,string+1):
        value=float(input("Enter string %a: "%num))
        print("No of positive whole numbers entered is:",IsPos(val)) 
        


def IsPos(val):
    counterVal=0;

    for whole_number in value:

        if val.is_integer() and val>=0:
            counterVal+=1

    return counterVal;

main()
```

Comment: You are casting the input to `float` and then test whether it's an `int`.

Comment: Your input is `float` but you test if type is `int`, I guess it could be your issue

Comment: @timgeb Whenever I remove the `float` it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Barbra nobody said you should remove the `float`.

Comment: @timgeb What should I do I am a little confused

Comment: @Barbra did you read the duplicate question?

Comment: @timgeb I am still confused after looking through that question where should I enter this statement `float.is.integer` into the code above

Comment: ... replace `if type(string) == int` with `string.is_integer()`.

Comment: and please use a less confusing variable name than `string` when you mean a number.

Comment: @timgeb would value be a better name

Comment: @Barbra yes, or `number`

Comment: @Barbra no problem. I suggest you try to figure out why your approach did not work.

Comment: @timgeb Can you help me with the editted problem above

Comment: @Barbra please post a new question if you have a new question